# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime C#.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC and cant find a solution to this error!

here is my model

> Scorecard.cs

```
 public partial class Scorecard
{
    public int ScorecardID { get; set; }
    public int VendorID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UpdatedBy { get; set; }
```

and my constructor in my ScorecardRepository.cs

```
        //CONSTRUCTOR
    public ScorecardRepository()
    {
        allScorecards = new List<Scorecard>();

        scorecardData = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/ScorecardXML.xml"));
        var scorecards = from scorecard in scorecardData.Descendants("item")
                         select new Scorecard((int)scorecard.Element("ScorecardID"), (int)scorecard.Element("VendorID"),
                             scorecard.Element("Title").Value, (bool)scorecard.Element("Enabled"),
                             (DateTime)scorecard.Element("Created"), (int)scorecard.Element("CreatedBy"),
                             (DateTime)scorecard.Element("LastUpdated"), (int)scorecard.Element("UpdatedBy"));
        allScorecards.AddRange(scorecards.ToList<Scorecard>());
    }
```

so everything works apart from a DateTime error i am getting which is really confusing me as to why it keeps happening...

ERROR

[image]

all help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the format of the date in the XML file?

Comment: XML FILE so far **<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<scorecard>
  <item>
    <ScorecardID>1</ScorecardID>
    <VendorID>1</VendorID>
    <Title>Something</Title>
    <Enabled>True</Enabled>
    <Created>1</Created>
    <CreatedBy>123</CreatedBy>
    <LastUpdated>1</LastUpdated>
    <UpdatedBy>123</UpdatedBy>
  </item>
</scorecard>**

Comment: May I ask; How would you think convert 1 to datetime correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

How about trying:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(scorecard.Element("Created").Value)
```

Comment: that allows a build but throws back this error [System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' to type 'System.IConvertible'.]

Comment: can you go like so (don't really have code handy to test this against, but i think it should work....) `Convert.ToDateTime(scorecard.Element("Created").ToString())`

Comment: Maybe it is as simple as adding ".Value"? I've edited the answer above.

Comment: Not sure if it's looking for Value or ToString, but i'm guessing one of the two will work.

Comment: For all I know it could be `.Value.ToString()` or something entirely different. Interested to find out the correct answer.

Comment: .Value like the Nullable "UpdatedBy" but not the "Created"... String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: I think this answer ought to work - if it doesn't work, are you sure your strings represent valid dates?

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, the Convert function should be used for the int values too...I've had that backfire on me by directly casting it in some CRM 2011 linq queries that I've done.

Answer (score 0):

When reading data out of the XDocument, you need to parse the dates rather than cast:

```
DateTime.Parse(scorecard.Element("Created"))
```

Comment: Tried that! it gives me the following [Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments C:\solutions\Web\VisualStudio2010\VendorScorecard\VendorScorecard-Good01062014\VendorScorecard\Models\ScorecardRepository.cs 24 34 VendorScorecard
] and [Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' to 'string' C:\solutions\Web\VisualStudio2010\VendorScorecard\VendorScorecard-Good01062014\VendorScorecard\Models\ScorecardRepository.cs 24 49 VendorScorecard
]

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Do you need to cast explicitly to XElement before the explicit cast to DateTime? i.e.:</strike>

<strike>(DateTime)(XElement)(scorecard.Element("Created")), ...</strike>

Your cast should work with a valid string but, having seen your XML, there are values in there that cannot be parsed into dates. You'll need to check for FormatExceptions when you convert, if the data are not always going to be valid.

Comment: still saying.. String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: What is the value of the string in question?

Comment: this happens when i simple try to load the view

Comment: The exception message suggests that an instance of your ScorecardRepository class is created when you do that, and that something about your XML is the causing the exception. Can you not post the XML (or at least a sample of it)?

Comment: scorecard.Element("Created") already an `XElement`, why you are casting again? Completely unnecessary

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<scorecard>
  <item>
    <ScorecardID>1</ScorecardID>
    <VendorID>1</VendorID>
    <Title>Something</Title>
    <Enabled>True</Enabled>
    <Created>1</Created>
    <CreatedBy>123</CreatedBy>
    <LastUpdated>1</LastUpdated>
    <UpdatedBy>123</UpdatedBy>
  </item>
</scorecard>`

Comment: Yes, I think you are right, @Selman. But all of the answers given are unnecessary - the OP's original cast should work (check MSDN for XElement Conversion methods). There is clearly an invalid value in the XML

Comment: Will "1" convert successfully to a DateTime...?

Comment: You should post that XML in your question - the problem is the values of the Created and UpdatedBy elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should never trust the input. Use TryParse before you cast anything into any other type except string. And you should check for null values (especially for nullable types). Should it still throw exceptions, they are better managed (by you).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

(DateTime)Convert.ToDateTime(scorecard.Element("Created").Value),

in

public ScorecardRepository()
{

}